# how to change computer CMD username?

Tags: windows-10

I have changed my computer name but in some places, it remain the same like in C drive, CMD etc, I'm not able to solve this problem, will anyone help me?

EVER IN 2019 : 
dos / adm,

system/adm > net user 
list then del/add  |*… ? command where did modified DOS username , but it is not work these day ?

Since the newly recovered system OEM won't be kept step give UserName correct just directed decided by hotmail.com when installing by processing recover, so ALL OF FILES would no longer belonged to the old OS in own name but not nick name of Microsoft's Hotmail.

Since a new image for 1 license of 1 machine , OEM alerting me to saving file redirect required , authority removing requested … which is changed dos username however , 2nd OS just not by >net user ?

Yeah, why not use Hotmail in one name of real name where just keep in OEM own real name ?  Good Question(s)…. since my experience 1998 using OEM one brand , with started Hotmail.com , Microsoft through over force down using Hotmail.com but insisted to today , it is there. . . ah..., and so many unknown and networks issues never solved included Microsoft 's so on for client user not in organization or company even to open  a case pay for supports...,

Please help on how to CHANG dos user name back to OLDER os '  own real name instead "forced" to use Microsoft nick name of dos please !? As so far, anyone , can possible use a nick name to do anything via it , when the real name could not have been clarified with ISP , OEM , Route Service at a wire-plan and wire net map today … ah...,

Sincerely

Comment: It is not at all clear what you are asking. Please expand your question to give examples of what has changed and what has not.

Comment: The computer name is not the same as the user name

Comment: If you post some screenshot, we'll be able to understand your problem better.

Comment: Are you talking about your computer's name, or your login name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are folders created when you first login to a computer with your username: `C:\Users\<username>`

When you change your username Windows does NOT rename these folders. To do so could potentially break substantial parts of your computer: Links, shortcuts, programs, and other things could stop working if the name of that folder changed.

If you MUST all parts of your computer update to reflect your new username, do NOT change your username, but create a new user entirely with the new correct username.

Creating a new user account will create new folders with the correct name. You can then copy over necessary files and folders and they should work properly.